# docker hub images tags are not showing using automated build from github organisation repo

Tags: github, docker, dockerhub

I have setup automated builds on docker hub, using two different github accounts.

1. Personal github account
    
    docker hub image: atifsaddique/base
2. An organisation called stakator

    docker hub repo: https://hub.docker.com/r/stakater/base/tags/

When I setup automated build using my **personal account**, the tags are shown properly on docker hub,

but when I setup automated build using **stakator**, the build succeeds fine, but the tags are not shown on docker hub.

I can still pull the image with latest tag, but the tag is not being shown on docker hub tags page.

here is the same type of question but with no proper answer.
 
 https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was reported on docker hub forum also, and it is resolved by docker hub team. The tags are showing properly now.
https://hub.docker.com/r/stakater/base/tags/